# Port forwarding is failing on Cisco router 1841

Tags: cisco

I have configured PNAT on my router. Everything seems fine. I have static NAT set for port forwarding for servers behind the NAT router.

I have setup ACLs to open the ports that are being forwarded on the Ext. Interface

but when I do a port scan, only ssh is open, the rest of the ports are closed.

Does any one have an idea as to why this is so? Thx

Conf:

```
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname OME-GW
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
dot11 syslog
ip source-route
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ip bootp server
ip domain name *******
ip name-server [x.x.x.x]
ip name-server [x.x.x.x]
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 8.8.4.4
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1841 sn XXXXXXX

!
redundancy
!
!
ip ssh port 22 rotary 1
!
class-map match-all win_kasp_updates_allow
 match protocol http url "/.geo.kaspersky.com"
 match protocol http url "/.windowsupdate.com"
 match protocol http url "/update.windows.com"
 match protocol http url "/windowsupdate.microsoft.com"
 match protocol http url "/downloads4.kaspersky-labs.com"
 match access-group 10
class-map match-all everything_else
 match any
!
!
policy-map win_kasp_updates_allow_policy
 class win_kasp_updates_allow
   drop
 class everything_else
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.21 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 103 in
 ip flow ingress
 ip flow egress
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 !
 service-policy input win_kasp_updates_allow_policy
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address [Public_IP] 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group 102 in
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 !
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 no fair-queue
 clock rate 2000000
 !
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
 !
!
ip default-gateway [ISP_P2P_IP]
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip flow-export version 5
ip flow-export destination 192.168.1.151 9991
ip flow-top-talkers
 top 10
 sort-by bytes
!
ip dns server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 25 [Public_IP] 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 25 [Public_IP] 26 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 53 [Public_IP] 53 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.20 53 [Public_IP] 53 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 110 [Public_IP] 110 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.20 1194 [Public_IP] 1194 extendable
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [ISP_P2P_IP]
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 deny   192.168.1.22
access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq pop3
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq smtp
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq 1194
access-list 102 permit udp any any
access-list 102 permit tcp any any
access-list 102 permit icmp any [ISP_P2P_IP] 0.0.0.3 echo
access-list 102 permit icmp any [ISP_P2P_IP] 0.0.0.3 echo-reply
access-list 102 deny   ip host 195.154.109.72 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 127.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 255.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 224.0.0.0 31.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip host 0.0.0.0 any
access-list 103 deny   ip host 192.168.1.9 any
access-list 103 deny   ip host 192.168.1.35 any
access-list 103 permit ip any any
access-list 103 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 103 permit udp host 192.168.1.26 eq domain any
access-list 103 permit tcp host 192.168.1.26 eq domain any
access-list 103 permit udp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
no cdp run

!
!
!
!
snmp-server community secret RO 90
!
!
control-plane
 !
!

!
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 5 0
 login local
 rotary 1
 transport input ssh
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Show ip nat translations

```
Pro Inside global         Inside local          Outside local         Outside global
udp [Public_IP]:137    192.168.1.16:137      192.168.255.255:137   192.168.255.255:137
udp [Public_IP]:138    192.168.1.16:138      192.168.255.255:138   192.168.255.255:138
tcp [Public_IP]:25     192.168.1.20:25       ---                   ---
tcp [Public_IP]:53     192.168.1.20:53       ---                   ---
udp [Public_IP]:53     192.168.1.20:53       ---                   ---
tcp [Public_IP]:110    192.168.1.20:110      ---                   ---
udp [Public_IP]:1194   192.168.1.20:1194     ---                   ---
tcp [Public_IP]:38682  192.168.1.52:38682    196.0.3.118:80        196.0.3.118:80
```

Comment: Please show us your configuration.

Comment: I tried posting the conf but it appears disorganised can you suggest the best way to post it while still maintaining the formatting for better readability?

Comment: Paste it, highlight the config, then click the button with the curly braces { }

Comment: Thx Jordan. I have added the Conf

Comment: Your ACL 102 will allow the ingress traffic to any UDP/TCP port. When you perform a port scan of the ports that you've included in your static PAT list, what does `show ip nat translations` show? Have you verified the host 192.168.1.20 is listening/responding to the static PAT port list in your config?

Comment: Is 1.21 the default gateway for 1.20? If the traffic doesn't come back to this router (1.21), it won't work.

Comment: @one.time Yes, The host 192.168.1.20 is listening on all these ports. Results for the NAT table translations is shown up

Comment: @Ricky Beam. Man you so through the problem to the solution. I could not see that because I thought the host and the gateway being on the same LAN would be just fine. I was still having my mail server connected to the old ISP until I had sorted out the port forwarding issue. Thank you man and whoever has taken their time to look into my problem. I am so grateful. Problem solved.

Comment: Problem solved. How can I mark it as so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ricky Beam. Man you so through the problem to the solution. I could not see that because I thought the host and the gateway being on the same LAN would be just fine. I was still having my mail server connected to the old ISP until I had sorted out the port forwarding issue. Thank you man and whoever has taken their time to look into my problem. I am so grateful.  Solution was to have my server to point to 192.168.1.21 as its gateway. Problem solved